# Installing NServiceBus Infrastructure

Tags: nservicebus

I'm currently trying out NServiceBus and it's working well on my system. Now I would like to install it on one of our internal servers to document what needs to be done to setup nservicebus from scratch. My current strategy was to invoke `NServiceBus.Host /installInfrastructure` which seems to work, it reported installing RavenDB and Msmq and DTC. However when I try to run my sample application (as an administrator) i get an exception:

```
2012-12-07 15:13:43,599 [1] FATAL NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost [(null)] <(null)> - System.InvalidOperationException: There is a problem with the input queue: FormatName:DIRECT=OS:dev\private$\els.bus.els.service. See the enclosed exception for details. ---> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_Transactional()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.get_Transactional()
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageReceiver.QueueIsTransactional()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageReceiver.QueueIsTransactional()
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageReceiver.Init(Address address, Boolean transactional)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.ITransport.Start(Address address)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IStartableBus.Start(Action startupAction)
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start()
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Did you create the queues or let NSB create them?

Comment: Some questions: What profile are you running in? Is the machine you are running this code on named `dev`? Otherwise you're trying to create a remote queue, which requires privileges on that machine. If this is the local machine, have you tried creating queues manually? What happens if you create the queue `els.bus.els.service` before running the host?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to installing the infrastructure, you need to invoke the /install flag to get your queues created (which requires admin privileges).

Comment: This seemed to install the apps as services though. Is that required to get the queues created?

Comment: If you run them in debug mode via Visual Studio, then the queues are created without installing the process as a Windows service.